# Using Random in multiple threads sharing same method

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I'm using to following xaml to create a simple racer app

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="racerOne" Maximum="1000"/>
    <Slider x:Name="racerTwo" Maximum="1000"/>
    <Button Content="Start Race" Click="myButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I use the following code

```
    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task firstRacer = Task.Run(() => Race(racerOne));
        Task secondRacer = Task.Run(() => Race(racerTwo));
    }

    private void Race(Slider racer)
    { 
        int step = 0;

        while (step < 1000)
        {
            step += new Random().Next(0, 10);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => racer.Value = step));
            Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(0, 300));
        }
    }
```

Most of the times (let's say 90% precent) both sliders appear to move together, while in debug I can see each thread generates different values for `step`. How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Random` is seeded by the clock; you might want to do something like:

```
Random rand1 = new Random();
Random rand2 = new Random(rand1.Next());
Task firstRacer = Task.Run(() => Race(racerOne, rand1));
Task secondRacer = Task.Run(() => Race(racerTwo, rand2));

private void Race(Slider racer, Random rand)
{ 
    int step = 0;

    while (step < 1000)
    {
        step += rand.Next(0, 10);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => racer.Value = step));
        Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(0, 300));
    }
}
```

This creates two separate `Random` instances *with different seeds* (by using the 1st to seed the second), and then passes these into the `Race` as arguments. This removes any risk of overly-predictable behaviour due to timing.

Comment: Seeding one random from the other is the trick. didn't think of that. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your random generator outside of the loop.

```
var rand = new Random();
while (step < 1000)
        {
            step += rand.Next(0, 10);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => racer.Value = step));
            Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(0, 300));
        }
```

For more details please go through this Jon Skeet's article:
https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx

> Almost every Stack Overflow question which includes the words "random"
>   and "repeated" has the same basic answer. It's one of the most common
>   "gotchas" in .NET, Java, and no doubt other platforms: creating a new
>   random number generator without specifying a seed will depend on the
>   current instant of time. The current time as measured by the computer
>   doesn't change very often compared with how often you can create and
>   use a random number generator – so code which repeatedly creates a new
>   instance of Random and uses it once will end up showing a lot of
>   repetition.

Comment: this produces the same result, but generating 2 different instances making one seed the other like @MarcGravell suggested worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `Random` object, it seeds it from the system clock. This has a resolution of only a few milliseconds, so if you create a new `Random` object more frequently than that, it will produce the same random sequence as the previous one.

The solution is to create only ONE random object (and use a `lock` to serialise access to it if more than one thread is accessing it at once).

Comment: I thought about that, but in a "race" scenario, using a `lock` over a critical component seems to be undesirable; ok, in reality both threads will use the lock *about* as often, but it creates an artificial blockage IMO.

Comment: @MarcGravell True, using two separate instances would be quicker.